# How to setup two phase commit in FireDac?

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Does FireDac support two phase commit transaction?  If it does, how can I do two phase commit using FireDac in Delphi to perform update on two firebird database? Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of the way for FireDAC. Its transaction objects can work only with a single connection. For other libraries (as I don't believe they considered FireDAC) applies [this note](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Managing_Transactions_in_Multi-tiered_Applications): _"Only the BDE- and ADO-based data access components support two-phase commit. Do not use InterbaseExpress or dbExpress components if you want to have transactions that span multiple databases."_

Comment: What's more, only ODBC Firebird driver seems to support 2PC. So at the ODBC low level you may succeed.

Comment: I know FIBPlus's transaction can do two phase commit.  But when migrated to FireDAC I cannot find a way to do it :(

Comment: I could help, but only on low, ODBC level (with Firebird ODBC driver as the native driver fbclient.dll doesn't seem to support that, but that's what I cannot say for sure, maybe expert like @Mark Rotteveel can say).

Comment: Thanks Victoria, but I don't really want to use ODBC driver because my project is already heavily used FireDAC.  I will drop two phase commit if FireDAC doesn't support.  Any good alternatives to two phase commit can you suggest?