# Two FireDAC FDConnections and FDQuery's controlled by one FDTransaction ends with error: [FireDAC][Phys][FB]-343. Cannot set default transaction

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I have old Delphi (XE6) project for a Firebird 2.5 database with IBX (IBExpress) components, where two IBDatabases controlled by one IBTransaction. When I commit (or rollback) the active transaction, modifications in both databases are committed (or rolled back) too. Firebird server support multidatabase transaction, see: [3.7. Multi-database applications in the Firebird documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/ufb/using-firebird.html#ufb-cs-multidb)

Now, I need this function with Delphi XE6 FireDAC components, but when I try to run ExecSQL or Open select in both FDQuery, method Prepare in one FDQuery crashes with error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][FB]-343. Cannot set default transaction

I was looking for a solution, but my problem is very rare, I did not find anything. FireDAC components support AutoStart and AutoStop transactions, but I have disabled this support, I want to manage the transactions manually. To test, you need two Firebird databases and use any SQL statement.

My test project, only Form and one Button:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  FireDAC.Phys.IBBase, FireDAC.Phys.FB, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet,
  FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Comp.UI;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FDTranBeforeCommit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FDTranBeforeRollback(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDGUIxWaitCur: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
  FDPhysFBDriv: TFDPhysFBDriverLink;
  FDCon1: TFDConnection;
  FDCon2: TFDConnection;
  FDTrx: TFDTransaction;
  FDQry1: TFDQuery;
  FDQry2: TFDQuery;
begin
  FDGUIxWaitCur := TFDGUIxWaitCursor.Create(nil);
  FDPhysFBDriv := TFDPhysFBDriverLink.Create(nil);
  FDPhysFBDriv.VendorLib := 'C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\WOW64\fbclient.dll';   { 32 bit applications on 64 bit Firebird }
  FDCon1 := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  FDCon2 := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  FDTrx  := TFDTransaction.Create(nil);
  FDQry1 := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FDQry2 := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      FDTrx.Options.AutoCommit := False;
      FDTrx.Options.AutoStart := False;
      FDTrx.Options.AutoStop := False;
      FDTrx.BeforeCommit := FDTranBeforeCommit;
      FDTrx.BeforeRollback := FDTranBeforeRollback;

      FDCon1.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
      FDCon1.TxOptions.AutoStart := False;
      FDCon1.TxOptions.AutoStop := False;
      FDCon1.Params.Clear;
      FDCon1.Params.Add('DriverID=FB');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('Database=c:\a\dbone.fdb');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('Server=LOCALHOST/3050');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('Protocol=TCPIP');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('user_name=NAME');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('password=passw');
      FDCon1.Params.Add('lc_ctype=WIN1250');

      FDCon2.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
      FDCon2.TxOptions.AutoStart := False;
      FDCon2.TxOptions.AutoStop := False;
      FDCon2.Params.Clear;
      FDCon2.Params.Add('DriverID=FB');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('Database=c:\a\dbtwo.fdb');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('Server=LOCALHOST/3050');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('Protocol=TCPIP');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('user_name=NAME');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('password=passw');
      FDCon2.Params.Add('lc_ctype=WIN1250');

      FDCon1.Transaction := FDTrx;
      FDCon2.Transaction := FDTrx;

      FDQry1.Connection := FDCon1;
      FDQry1.Transaction := FDTrx;

      FDQry2.Connection := FDCon2;
      FDQry2.Transaction := FDTrx;

      FDCon1.Open;
      FDCon2.Open;
      if FDTrx.Active then
        ShowMessage('trx active');
      if not FDTrx.Active then
        FDTrx.StartTransaction;
      if FDTrx.Active then
        ShowMessage('trx active');

      FDQry2.Close;
      FDQry2.SQL.Text := 'select count(id) from table';
      FDQry2.Prepare;
      FDQry2.Open;
      ShowMessage(Format('DBTwo table records count %d',[FDQry2.Fields[0].AsInteger]));
      FDQry2.Close;

      if FDTrx.Active then
        ShowMessage('trx active');

      FDQry1.Close;
      FDQry1.SQL.Text := 'select count(id) from table';
      FDQry1.Prepare; { An error appears here }
      FDQry1.Open;
      ShowMessage(Format('DBOne table records count %d',[FDQry1.Fields[0].AsInteger]));
      FDQry1.Close;

      if FDTrx.Active then
        FDTrx.Commit;
    except on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
        if FDTrx.Active then
          FDTrx.Rollback;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FDQry2.Close;
    FDQry1.Close;
    FDCon2.Close;
    FDCon1.Close;
    FDQry2.Free;
    FDQry1.Free;
    FDTrx.Free;
    FDCon2.Free;
    FDCon1.Free;
    FDPhysFBDriv.Free;
    FDGUIxWaitCur.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FDTranBeforeCommit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Trx BeforeCommit');
end;

procedure TForm1.FDTranBeforeRollback(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Trx BeforeRollback');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437776/how-to-setup-two-phase-commit-in-firedac

Probabl impossible in AnyDAC/FireDAC

Comment: As i know RDBMS - one connection can have one or more transactions, but not one transaction for multiply connection. Maybe component library can internaly somehow handle it in Delphi it's self, but i think you just have wrong program desing.

Comment: @OleksandrMorozevych "one transaction in multiple connections" is supported in Interbase/Firebird, with some limits. Just like other databases might support "queries to external/seconary server" or "sharding", etc. But this RDBMS-specific mode seems to be not implemented in AnyDAC

Comment: @OleksandrMorozevych These are basically 2 phase transactions which are coordinating their commit or roll back (a.k.a distributed transactions/XA).